# Screen Record Full Resolution Chrome Mobile Responsive Screen

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, screen-capture, screen-recording

I'm trying to record our software in Chrome's mobile device emulator. The resolution for the hypothetical device is 1080 x 1920 (vertical orientation). I would like to be able to just record the emulation screen at full resolution. I know I could record my entire screen and just crop for the window showing the software, but then it does not record at the proper 1080 x 1920 resolution and looks blurry. Does anyone have any methods for recording just the emulation screen at full size?

Essentially, I want to record the red boxed area in full resolution (which should be 1080 x 1920)
[Chrome Screen Emulation Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVh2P.jpg)

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can't "record" it in 1920/1080 because it literally isn't in that resolution. those pixels don't exist.

A few ideas come to mind -

- Record on a 4k (or higher) monitor, the same area will have more
  pixels.

  - if you don't have one handy (and have an nvidia graphics card):
    try using [Dynamic super resolution](https://pointerclicker.com/can-you-record-in-4k-without-a-4k-monitor/)
- **Literally** [rotate you display](https://operating-systems.wonderhowto.com/how-to/rotate-display-linux-mac-windows-computers-0160742/) and record it in the correct orientation ("portrait"). it will be able to occupy MUCH more screen area, and the cropped-out area will be significantly smaller. therefore, the video dimensions will still be large.

  - Move away the console (un-dock or just close), make sure the emulator is taking up as much space as possible.
- Verify you're recording (and editing and exporting) in the highest resolution possible. that's how it looks like in [obs studio](https://www.alphr.com/obs-record-part-screen/):

[image: obs studio]

Maybe use a [Virtual Machine](https://www.guru99.com/best-virtual-machine-software.html) if you don't wanna mess up your desktop environment?

Comment: Thank you, yeah I ended up doing the rotated display solution. Forgot to close this question lol